# Vulkan - what "stages" exist out of a render pass for setting in vkCmdPipelineBarrier command

Tags: pipeline, vulkan, barrier

What stages can be set for `srcStageMask/dstStageMask` when submitting a `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` out of a renderpass, because in such case there is no subpass bind point to graphics pipeline?

The same question for when submitting `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` in subpass that has a bind point to a compute pipeline which I guess doesn't have stages like VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT and maybe many more.

Thanks

**Edit**

First, thanks to @Nicol Bolas comment,  **a compute shader can not be dispatched in middle of subpass**.

And I would like to clarify my question:

Say I have an image that after a renderpass will have the layout of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL.

After the renderpass, I want to update the image with new data and wish to change its layout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL.

Thus, after recording vkCmdEndRenderPass I record a vkCmdPipelineBarrier command as follows:

```
const VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier =
{
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,     
    nullptr,                                    
    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,                  // srcAccessMask
    VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,               // dstAccessMask
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,   // oldLayout
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,       // newLayout
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                    
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                    
    image,                                      
    {                                           // subresourceRange
        VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,              // aspectMask
        0,                                      // baseMipLevel
        VK_REMAINING_MIP_LEVELS,                // levelCount
        0,                                      // baseArrayLayer
        VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS               // layerCount
    }
};

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(currentCommandBuffer,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                     0,
                     0, nullptr,
                     0, nullptr,
                     1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
```

This ensures transition waits as long as previous command within renderpass still didn't cross the fragment shader stage.

But what if vulkan executes vkCmdPipelineBarrier after renderpass execution already finished? now there is no bound pipeline , no stages - does it means the barrier will go into an endless wait until a new renderpass will begin and a fragment shader stage will happen?

Comment: You cannot dispatch a compute shader in the middle of a subpass. So that question is moot. Also, which stages to use are a function of what kind of synchronization you're doing. What the writing and consuming operations are.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas, I edit and clarified the question. There is something I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got everything right, then what you want to synchronize is the following:
You would like to ensure that the image is not overwritten with new data before a preceding renderpass has finished *reading* the image.

To achieve this, you have set up barriers which synchronize

```
Execution:   FRAGMENT_SHADER            ->   TRANSFER
Memory:      SHADER_READ                ->   TRANSFER_WRITE
Layout:      SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL   ->   TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
```

While these synchronization parameters ensure correctness, they are actually a bit more than necessary. The `srcAccessMask` is used for memory that needs to be "made available", which means ~transfer into L2 memory, so that it can be accessed afterwards.

This is the part which is unnecessary in your barrier, because the memory *already is* available (in L2 memory), otherwise it could not have been read properly.

I.e. the optimal barrier would be as follows:

```
Execution:   FRAGMENT_SHADER            ->   TRANSFER
Memory:      0                          ->   TRANSFER_WRITE
Layout:      SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL   ->   TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
```

---

Now to the question about

> But what if vulkan executes vkCmdPipelineBarrier after renderpass execution already finished?

What a recorded barrier like those above tell your GPU is the following:

- Within the current queue, wait for all preceding commands which have a `FRAGMENT_SHADER` stage to have completed their `FRAGMENT_SHADER` stages before continuing with subsequent commands in their `TRANSFER` stages.

That also means:

- If there are no previous commands in the queue, the requirement of the barrier is already fulfilled and execution of further commands can continue immediately.
- If there are commands in the queue that do not potentially go through `FRAGMENT_SHADER` stages, we don't wait for them.
- The barrier applies to every command that has ever been submitted to the queue. (But most commands will no longer be "in flight" but will already have been removed because they have completed execution.) The `src` dependencies of a barrier *never* refer to something that might be submitted in the future, only to things that have been submitted previously.

If you have difficulties with these things, you might want to have a look at the [Introduction to Vulkan](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes) lecture which covers such synchronization topics from [22:28](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes?t=1348) onwards.

Comment: What makes your barrier more optimal? Sounds just a matter of code style...

Comment: Thanks @joohi, the video also very informative. It is really not intuitive subject!

Comment: @krOoze It could be argued that "my" barrier is more optimal for two reasons: 1) There can not be any doubt for the compiler w.r.t. the `src` access, i.e. it is clear that no memory is to be made available in this case. Now, if you would counter that no compiler would act so stupid and make memory available in this case, I would totally agree. But still: 2) It has a didactic effect by pointing out that no `READ` access flags make sense with `srcAccessMask` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just inspect the [Valid Usage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkCmdPipelineBarrier).

All of them are permitted, except those that have its feature disabled on whole device (e.g. geometry shader), or those the queue family does not support.

For subpass dependencies, only those supported by `pipelineBindPoint` pipeline (i.e. currently just graphics) are allowed.

---

I think the main problem that makes you deeply confused is that you think *pipeline* is a *finite state machine*. But pipeline is not a FSM, it is a pipeline (as the name suggests). It always exists (as do all its stages), even if nothing currently flows through the pipeline.

Specifically, in english your barrier simply says: "Before any commands recorded after me start copying into this image, make sure all commands recorded before me finished reading this image as texture."

When stages "exist" is not a valid question (as explained above); existence and non-existence is not really a property they have. And as you see in the semantics of the barrier, it would not even matter to change its meaning.

Some stages are forbidden by the valid usage, but that is more to reduce confusion than anything. Even if they weren't forbidden, it would change nothing. The barriers with such stages would simply be no-op, or would translate to logically-earlier or later stage.

Comment: @krOooze - Thanks ,  edit and clarified the question. There is something I miss

Comment: @audi02 Tried to address some of that in update.